# Azure Resource Manager template chained functions

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to remove `/` from the URL using azure function before assigning to output variable value

```
"webappStorageUri":{
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[take(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('webappStorageName'))).primaryEndpoints.web, length(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('webappStorageName'))).primaryEndpoints.web)-1]"
 }
```

Returned value from [`length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#length) function should be the value for [`take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#take) function. This is not working. I get following error on deployment. I don't get anything out of this error message. Does Azure support chained function execution? Is this is right approach to remove `/` from the URL?

Error message

```
[error]Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'Unable to parse language expression 'take(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('webappStorageName'))).primaryEndpoints.web, length(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('webappStorageName'))).primaryEndpoints.web)-1': expected token 'RightParenthesis' and actual 'Integer'.'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your function has issues with brackets, and you cannot really substract by appending `-1` in a random place.

```
"[take(reference(variables('webappStorageName')).primaryEndpoints.web,
    sub(length(reference(variables('webappStorageName')).primaryEndpoints.web), 1))]"
```

line breaks for readability only

Comment: I was trying to remove `/` at the end of the URL. This works. Thanks!